# How to convert IP address stored in a table into hexadecimal? the output I am expecting is 00:00:8D:69:DF:B6 for an IP 141.105.223.182

Tags: sql-server, hex, ssms-2017

I used this for converting a IP address, (I read this from web not my SQL). I now want to understand how can I convert an IP address stored in a column to HEXADECIMAL.

```
DECLARE @IP varchar(30) 
SET @IP = '192.168.1.1'

SELECT 

'00:00:'+
RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME(@IP, 4) AS int)), 2),2) + ':'
+
RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME(@IP, 3) AS int)), 2),2) + ':'
+
RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME(@IP, 2) AS int)), 2),2) + ':'
+
RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME(@IP, 1) AS int)), 2),2)
```

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using in tags

Comment: I am using SQL server management studio 2017

Comment: As I understand your question you want to know how to convert a table column (instead of a variable)? Answer: replace `@IP` with the name of your column and add `FROM`

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work with your code? The desired output is for an IP of 141.105.223.182 but in your example you have a different IP address. If you change your variable to the same IP as in the title of your question you get the EXACT output you claim you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your almost there already!

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to replace @IP with a table's column data

You just need to add a from and change the selection criteria

I create a temp table #testdata to demonstrate, you just need to select FROM your table

```
create table #testdata
([IP] varchar(25))

insert into #testdata
values
('192.168.1.1')
insert into #testdata
values
('192.168.1.2')
insert into #testdata
values
('192.168.1.3')

SELECT 
'00:00:'+
RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME([IP], 4) AS int)), 2),2) + ':'
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME([IP], 3) AS int)), 2),2) + ':'
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME([IP], 2) AS int)), 2),2) + ':'
+ RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(VARBINARY(4), CAST(PARSENAME([IP], 1) AS int)), 2),2) 
FROM #testdata
```